# Why is video/mp4 and video/webm blocked by noscript in TBB?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, security, noscript

Is it safe to disable the default blocking? Why was it added/turned on?

Having to click 'temporary allow' and sit through a page reload every time I want to watch a video or load one when scrolling on my Twitter feed is a bit annoying, but I'll understand if it's for a good reason

Comment: please read at least [this one](https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#TBBFlash) of the [Tor-FAQs](https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en).

Comment: video/mp4 and video/webm support are built-in to the browser, no plugins (like Flash) are required

Comment: i don't know where, but some time ago i read HTML5 video-tags are blocked for the same reasons... -- it's similar to PDF: for complete security they also shouldn't be read online; it's better to download them, go offline and open them in the dedicated document reader.

Comment: anyway... in Tails PDFs and HTML5-videos are enabled by default...!